# Trying to connect to IBM's Informix docker edition with JDBC

Tags: java, docker, jdbc, informix, dbeaver

I'm trying to write some Java tests for Informix. I have the docker running from here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/informix-developer-database/

I cannot find any example of the JDBC connection string to use to connect to it.

I used this to run it:  docker run -it --name ifx -h ifx --privileged -p 9089088 -p 9089:9089 -p 27017:27017 -p 27018:27018 -p 27883:27883 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest

I'm trying this jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/sysmaster:INFORMIXSERVER=ifx with their default username and password but I'm getting "INFORMIXSERVER does not match either DBSERVERNAME or DBSERVERALIASES."

I also tried with INFORMIXSERVER=dev - same error.

Anyone know what the jdbc url would be for this docker image?

Comment: Documentation appears to be [here](https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme/blob/master/12.10.FC12/informix-developer-database.md).

Comment: What port did you expose from your docker container when you started it? Also, what OS are you running this on?

Comment: I use this command to start it  docker run -it --name ifx -h ifx --privileged -p 9089088 -p 9089:9089 -p 27017:27017 -p 27018:27018 -p 27883:27883 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest

Comment: running docker on Mac OS

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah but they don't provide any JDBC url.

Comment: Try `INFORMIXSERVER=informix` instead of `INFORMIXSERVER=ifx`, That works for me. If it works for you, I'll provide more details on how I determined that.

Comment: @andrewjames Awesome! That does work!  You should post it as an answer and I'll give you the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following JDBC URL string:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/sysmaster:INFORMIXSERVER=informix
```

You can check the correct value to use for the `INFORMIXSERVER` parameter as follows:

1. Connect to your Docker instance as follows:

```
docker exec -it ifx bash
```

2. At the command line, check the contents of the `sqlhosts` file:

```
cat $INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts
```

You will see something similar to this (assuming a vanilla Docker installation):

```
############################################################
### DO NOT MODIFY THIS COMMENT SECTION
### HOST NAME = 6b4943a932ab
############################################################
informix        onsoctcp        *6b4943a932ab         9088
informix_dr     drsoctcp        *6b4943a932ab         9089
```

The entry for port 9088 has the name `informix`.

Comment: Also note that `INFORMIXSERVER=informix` is not required unless you are trying to look up stuff from  a SQLHOST file using JDBC. As long as you have a host:post, you can omit INFORMIXSERVER altogether and using a 4.10.JC6 or higher JDBC driver

Answer (score 3):

`INFORMIXSERVER=informix` is not required unless you are trying to look up stuff from a SQLHOST file using JDBC. As long as you have a host:post, you can omit INFORMIXSERVER altogether and using a 4.10.JC6 or higher JDBC driver.

This saves you the trouble of knowing the name of each Informix server